# Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor using this

Tags: java

Why can't I make second constructor using switch case statements that refer input to the first constructor? It shows error "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor using this". So it seems that I have to retype assignments from 1st constructor for every case statement in the second.

```
public class Card {
        public static final String CLUBS = "Clubs";
        public static final String DIAMONDS = "Diamonds";
        public static final String HEARTS = "Hearts";
        public static final String SPADES = "Spades";
        public static final int ACE = 1;
        public static final int JACK = 11;
        public static final int QUEEN = 12;
        public static final int KING = 13;

        public Card(int rank, String suit) {
            this.rank = rank;
            this.suit = suit;
        }

        public Card(String rank, String suit) {
            if (!isCorrectSuit(suit)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("incorrect suit");
            switch(rank) {
            case ACE: this(1, suit);
            case JACK: this(11, suit);
            case QUEEN: this(12, suit);
            case KING : this(13, suit);
            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("incorrect rank");
            }
        }



        private boolean isCorrectSuit(String suit) {
            return (suit.equals(CLUBS) || suit.equals(DIAMONDS) || suit.equals(HEARTS) || suit.equals(SPADES));
        }

        private boolean isCorrectRank(int rank) {
            return rank == 1 || rank == 11 || rank == 12 || rank == 13;
        }

        private int rank;
        private String suit;    

    }
```

Comment: In your shoes, I'd consider to write `enum`s for **both** suit and rank of cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for a static factory method where `this(...)` can be replaced with `new Card(...)`:

```
class Card {
    ...

    private Card(int rank, String suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public static Card of(String rank, String suit) {
        if (!isCorrectSuit(suit)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("incorrect suit");
        }

        final Card card;
        switch (Integer.valueOf(rank)) {
            case ACE:
                card = new Card(1, suit);
                break;
            case JACK:
                card = new Card(11, suit);
                break;
            case QUEEN:
                card = new Card(12, suit);
                break;
            case KING:
                card = new Card(13, suit);
                break;
            default: {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("incorrect rank");
            }
        }
        return card;
    }
}
```

These four instances can be predefined, you needn't create them over again.

---

I wonder why you didn't apply the same approach to the `rank` value:

```
public Card(int rank, String suit) {
    if (!isCorrectSuit(suit)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("incorrect suit");
    }

    if (!isCorrectRank(rank)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("incorrect rank");
    }

    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public Card(String rank, String suit) {
    this(Integer.valueOf(rank), suit);
}
```

Note that you've got 2 public constructors, and only one of them has a kind of validation. I can create a `new Card(2, "Unknown")` and will get no exceptions.

Other options for consideration might be:

- writing enums instead of primitive values
- writing sets of values to replace the `isCorrectX` methods with `Set#contains`

Comment: A less "extreme" way to do this is to write a static method that simply converts `String rank` to an `int`, and invoke that in the existing constructor: `this(stringRankToInt(rank), suit)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner it seems `stringRankToInt` simply means `Integer.valueOf`

Answer (score 0):

If you want invoke one constructor from another within the class you invoke it through `this(args)` key word with adequate arguments.

It's not fully clear which constructor you want to use in which, but I think this is more probable:

```
  public Card(int rank, String suit) {
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public static Card create(String rank, String suit) {

        if (!isCorrectSuit(suit)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("incorrect suit");
        switch(rank) {
        case ACE: new Card(1, suit); break;
        case JACK: new Card(11, suit); break;
        case QUEEN: new Card(12, suit); break;
        case KING : new Card(13, suit); break;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("incorrect rank");
        }
    }
```

you have a static method that lets you create an object of type `Card`.

Answer (score -1):

just add a static routine that converts your String to an int